# Why does my PHP code recognises NULL entities in my Oracle database as Unidentified Indexes?

Tags: php, oracle

I have a simple PHP coding which fetches data from a specific table within my Oracle database. It works fine in outputting the data from the tables on the PHP form but one thing I've noticed is my Error_Reporting function calls up several identical errors indicating there are unidentified indexes present in the table.

**My Code:**

```
<?php
include("ConnectionCode.php");

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ROVER';
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Rover ID</th> <th>Rover Name</th> <th>Launch_Date</th> 
<th>Arrival_Date</th> <th>Manufacturer</th> </tr>";


while($row= oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['ROVER_ID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['ROVER_NAME'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['LAUNCH_DATE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['ARRIVAL_DATE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row ['MANUFACTURER'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);

?>
```

I made the logical assumption that these indexes were due to the NULL values present within some fields of the table. But my question is mainly this, is there anything I can do in the code to fix this? Or is it not really an issue?

Comment: Is there an error message? What are NULL entities? What have indexes got to do with it? What isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The manual](http://php.net/oci_fetch_array) mentions:

> `mode`: An optional second parameter can be any combination of the
>   following constants:
>
> [...]
>   `OCI_RETURN_NULLS`: Creates elements for `NULL` fields. The
>   element values will be a PHP `NULL`.

I'm not very familiar with the OCI interface, but the implication here seems to be that yes, `NULL` fields are omitted by default, but you can return them by explicitly setting that flag:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC + OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
```

Comment: And reading http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html is even better :)